# Search display template for content search web part for task aggregation

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, cswp

In a site collection, I have about 4 task list setup each on separate subsites. So on the root level, I am using a content search web part and through query, I am showing tasks from all of these 4 task lists to show aggregated tasks in the web part. Here is the query i am using: **path:"https://**.sharepoint.com/sites/**"  ContentTypeId:0x0108* -RefinableString01:Completed**

RefineableString01 is a mapped managed property and its helping me showing non- completed  (task status other than completed)tasks.  Now the challenge I have is to show this web part as close as possible to an actual task list view which has Task name, due date, status, description as task headers/columns in CSWP and I believe it requires setting up a custom display template which I have not worked on at all.

Can someone help me setting up tabular view of tasks aggregation using custom template. FYI, I have already setup managed properties (mapping respective crawled properties to respective managed property called Refineablstring etc) for description, task status and due date.

Additionally, I would also like to show custom choice column called Investor (site column) in the CSWP along with other basic columns, I am waiting for it to get crawled, once crawled, I will setup a managed property for the same.

Can someone please help me with the cswp display template that I can use, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from Search Explained could be an good primer
https://searchexplained.com/display-template-for-tasks-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365/